# Compilation warning for void ** and void *

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question regarding `void*` and `void**` and I know this is sort of an old question and has been asked (somewhat) before in stackoverflow. So the question is the following:

When I compile this code with gcc 4.4.3 under ubuntu 10.10, I get the following warning:

```
zz.c: In function ‘main’:
zz.c:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘bar’ from incompatible pointer type
zz.c:9: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘float **’
```

why is it that its ok to pass variable x as an argument of foo() but its not ok to pass variable y as an argument of bar(). I can fix this by explicitly casting both variables into `void*` and `void**` as expected.

```
void foo (void* a){
}

void bar(void **a){
     *a = (float *) malloc(100*sizeof(float));
}

int main (){

    float *x = (float*) malloc(100*sizeof(float));
    foo(x);
    free(x);

    float *y;
    bar(&y);
    free(y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the c++ tag? This question is pure c.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`void *a` means that `a` points to an object of unknown type.  However, `a` itself is not an unknown type because `a` is known to have type `void*`.  Only the object that `a` points to has an unknown type.

`void **a` means that `a` points to an object of type `void*`.  The object that `*a` points to has an unknown type, but the object `*a` itself is a pointer with type `void*`.

`&y` is a pointer to an object of type `float*`.  `&y` is not a pointer to an object of type `void*`.

Comment: ... wait... that actually makes sense! +1 for awesome explanation.

Comment: And how would you fix the warning?

Comment: void bar(float * *a){

Answer (score 6):

The C++ standard allows for any pointer to be implicitly converted *to* a `void*`. But a `void**` is not the same thing as a `void*`; it is a pointer to a `void*`. Therefore, it falls under the rules for regular pointer conversions (ie: forbidden without a cast, with some exceptions).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the information in the other answers, `void*` acts as a generic pointer type in C.  There are things that are generic about it: any pointer (other than a pointer-to-function type) can be converted to void* and back again without loss of information, and a pointer expression (again, other than pointer-to-function) can be implicitly converted to `void*`.  (C++ has slightly different rules.)

You might think that `void**` is a generic pointer-to-pointer type, but it isn't.  It's a pointer to a specific type, namely to `void*`.  In fact, C doesn't have a generic pointer-to-pointer type.  But it does have a generic pointer type, so any code that tries to use `void**` as a generic pointer-to-pointer type can probably just use `void*` instead.